# I am getting error ORA-03113 at the time of startup database.

Tags: oracle

I am getting error ORA-03113 at the time of startup database. I removed some old archive log files as per solution I got on google. But still I am unable to startup db. But, I am able to connect other database (dbname: CTS) on same server. 
Please suggest solution on this

Please find below current OS and DB configuration details and received errors.

```
**DB version is : 11g
Linux version : Linux ctsvm.oraclexpert.com 2.6.18-194.el5PAE #1 SMP Mon Mar 29 20:19:03 EDT 2010 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux**
```

Error I received is as below:-
Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

```
[oracle@ctsvm dbs]$ cd
[oracle@ctsvm ~]$ export ORACLE_SID=DBAYOG
[oracle@ctsvm ~]$ sqlplus '/as sysdba'
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Sun Oct 27 00:52:39 2013
Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Connected to an idle instance.

SQL> startup
ORACLE instance started.
Total System Global Area  422670336 bytes
Fixed Size                  1344616 bytes
Variable Size             339741592 bytes
Database Buffers           75497472 bytes
Redo Buffers                6086656 bytes
Database mounted.
ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel
Process ID: 4293
Session ID: 1 Serial number: 5
```

Comment: Look in the alert log.

Comment: Hi DCookie, I check alert log and removed old archives from dir.[oracle@ctsvm archivelog]$ ls -lrth
total 24K
drwxr-x--- 2 oracle oinstall 4.0K Oct 21 01:30 2013_10_21
drwxr-x--- 2 oracle oinstall 4.0K Oct 23 21:50 2013_10_23
drwxr-x--- 2 oracle oinstall 4.0K Oct 24 00:00 2013_10_24
drwxr-x--- 2 oracle oinstall 4.0K Oct 24 03:35 2013_10_19
drwxr-x--- 2 oracle oinstall 4.0K Oct 24 03:36 2013_10_14
drwxr-x--- 2 oracle oinstall 4.0K Oct 27 00:15 2013_10_27

Comment: Did you find any ORA-0600 or 7445 errors in the alert log?

Comment: Not archive log, ALERT log.

Comment: Hi, Plz find the alert log ORA-19809: limit exceeded for recovery files ORA-00312: online log 3 thread 1: &apos;/u002/app/oracle/oradataORA-19815: WARNING: db_recovery_file_dest_size of 4196401152 bytes is 100.00% used, and has 0 remaining bytes available.
ORA-16038: log 3 sequence# 144 cannot be archived
ORA-00312: online log 3 thread 1: &apos;/u002/app/oracle/oradata/DBAYOG/redo03.log&apos;
ORA-00312: online log 3 thread 1: &apos;/u002/app/oracle/oradata/DBAYOG/redo03.log&apos;

Comment: --> Cleanup archives with rman. put database in mount.
backup archivelog all delete input; or delete archivelog all;

Answer (score 2):

In your case, it seems that database can not pass from mounted to open state, for any reason.
Please check alert log and any generated file in your trace directories.
EDIT: I removed comment about ORA-00600 (I wrongly read your post 1st time...)

Comment: Hi Igr, in alert.log i cant see ORA-00600 error. Please let me know the solutions on error ORA-03113.

Comment: I just had the same issue. Thank for pointing out that we should check alert log. I saw that it was `ORA-19809: limit exceeded for recovery files` I just followed [this](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_19809_limit_exceeded_for_recovery.htm) which recommends to increase size of flash_recovery_area with `ALTER SYSTEM SET DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST_SIZE=<put the new value here> SCOPE=BOTH;`

Answer (score 0):

Please utilize oraenv to make sure you have all environment variables set before startup.

```
. oraenv (don't forget the dot)
--> input the SID
sqlplus / as sysdba
startup force --performs a shutdown abort + startup
```

Comment: Dear Guys, now i am getting error ORA-01034 oracle not available. please suggest.

Comment: Please post output from:
cat /etc/oratab
set | grep ORA

Comment: Hi,plz find the o/p :- # This file is used by ORACLE utilities.  It is created by root.sh
#   $ORACLE_SID:$ORACLE_HOME:<N|Y>:
# Multiple entries with the same $ORACLE_SID are not allowed.

Comment: and... #set | grep ORA ?

Comment: o/p is : ORACLE_BASE=/u002/app/oracle
ORACLE_HOME=/u002/app/oracle/product/11.2.0
ORACLE_SID=DBAYOG

Comment: Hi Guys, This day I tried to startup the said db getting error of ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel. plz let me know the solution steps...

Comment: anybody knows solution on this issue???

Comment: Please update your question with relevant information. I want "echo $PATH", "set |grep TWO_TASK", "set | grep ORA", "whereis sqlplus", "set |grep TNS". Then with your oracle os account fire up the db. I would like to see all these steps in your output. Tip: Sometimes I use strace on sqlplus to see what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

The archive log backups are failing hence the archive logs are getting accumulated on the mount points making the DB to get into hung state. Increase the size of the `db_recovery_file_dest_size` parameter and open the database and check. It should work.

```
alter database mount;  
alter system set db_recovery_file_dest_size=<>G scope=both;  
alter database open;
```